# Numpy Indexing First Boolean

Tags: python, numpy

In a boolean array, I am trying to obtain the column index of the first True. argmax works with at least one True, but understandably max(False) is 0. I'm wondering what the best method would be, given a very large array.

```
name = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
boolarr = np.array([[True, False, False, True],
                    [False, False, True, True],
                    [False, False, False, False]])
colidx = np.argmax(boolarr,axis=1)
print(name[colidx]) #result: ['a', 'c', 'a'] desired: ['a', 'c', None]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of `argmax`, since the maximum of a row with all `False` *is* 0. However, you can use `any` to determine the rows that contain all `False`, and use `np.where` to mask your result:

```
out = name[colidx]
np.where(boolarr.any(1), out, None)
```

```
array(['a', 'c', None], dtype=object)
```